# Correct usage of DBMS_ALERT in a.NET application

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have a continuous running .NET app (Windows service) that keeps listening to an event table in Oracle and does stuff if an alert is fired.
I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess package.

I'm using the DBMS_ALERT package to accomplish my goal.

Following code is executed to listen to alerts:

```
string query = "BEGIN " +
                     "  dbms_alert.register(:Name);" +
                     "  dbms_alert.WaitOne(:Name, :Message, :Status, :timeout);" +
                     "  dbms_alert.remove(:Name);" +
               "END;";
```

This is exactly what I could find in the Oracle documentation.

The solution works, but I have 1 small **problem**
When an alert is fired, my application starts doing its stuff, and in parallel I start listening again (async).
But sometimes it takes a few seconds from removing the alert to re-registering the alert. And it happens on multiple occasions that I do miss alerts.

**Questions**
1) Is there a way that I can keep listening, also when alerts are fired, so I don't miss any events?
2) From a functional perspective, I find it strange that I have to register and remove the alert every time. Is this really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can keep listening, also when alerts are fired,
>   so I don't miss any events?

Yes. You register for listening to alerts **once** per DB session and you will receive all alerts afterwards. No need to re-register.

If you want to receive also alerts that were signalled prior to registering for listening, inspect the full specification of the `dbms_alert.register` procedure to find out:

```
procedure register(name in varchar2, cleanup in boolean default TRUE);
--  Register interest in an alert.  A session may register interest in
--    an unlimited number of alerts.  Alerts should be de-registered when
--    the session no longer has any interest (see 'remove').  This call
--    always performs a 'commit'.
--  Input parameters:
--    name
--      The name of the alert in which this session is interested.
--      WARNING:  Alert names beginning with 'ORA$' are reserved for use for
--      products provided by Oracle Corporation.  Name must be 30 bytes
--      or less.  The name is case-insensitive.
--    cleanup
--      This specifies whether we should perform cleanup of any orphaned
--      pipes that may exist and are used by the dbms_alert package. This
--      cleanup is only performed on the first call to "register" for each
--      package instantiation. The default for the parameter is TRUE.
```

**Note** the second, optional parameter `cleanup`, defaulting to `true`. Pass it as `false` and your session never misses an alert signalled prior to registering.

> From a functional perspective, I find it strange that I have to
>   register and remove the alert every time. Is this really necessary?

No, it's not necessary.

As for the re-registering, see above.

As for the removal of the alerts... It's a badly written piece of documentation. The `remove` and `removeall` procedures do not remove alerts from alert "queue", they simply make your DB session stop listening to alerts, i.e., the `remove` is opposite to `register`.